# How to change null word value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

i import data from json file ,how can I replace null word by No phone number if the value of number_phone is empty or null ?
My code:

```
Widget listcard(
   String bg, String nom, String address, String temps, dynamic number_phone) {
 void _launchCaller(dynamic number) async {
   var Url = "tel:${number.toString()}";
   if (await canLaunch(Url)) {
     await launch(Url);
   } else {
     throw 'could not place call';
   }
 }
....
....
           child: RaisedButton.icon(
             onPressed: () {
               _launchCaller(number_phone);
             },
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
             label: Text(
               number_phone == null || number_phone == '' ? 'No phone number' : '$number_phone',
               style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.white,
                   fontSize: 15,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
             ),
             icon: Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.white, size: 36.0),
             splashColor: Colors.red,
             color: Colors.green[400],
        ....
        ....
```

image explain null words when No number phone founded [image of RaisedButton when number phone is null or empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aLHt.png)

Answer (score 0):

empty or null that's. important by the way codes below can help you

```
'${number_phone.isEmpty ? '' : number_phone}'
'${number_phone ?? ''}'
```

first line is for empty second one for null

Comment: not working always i receive the word null  if there is no number phone in json file, i want to replace null by 'pas de téléphone'

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

`number_phone ?? 'No phone number'`

or:

`number_phone == null || number_phone == '' ? 'No phone number' : '$number_phone',`

Comment: not working always i receive the word null if there is no number phone in json file, i want to replace null by 'pas de téléphone'

Comment: @flutter87 are you sure you didn't use `'${''` in `number_phone`? I tried that too and worked perfectly if I didn't use `'${''` to wrap `number_phone`. if still doesn't work maybe you can `print(number_phone)` and show us the result.

Comment: thank you but not working again, i add more informations to my poste

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it by adding `?? 'No phone'` in json instruction like this :

```
 '${data[i]["téléphone"]?? 'No phone'}'
```